# Oracle SQL hierarical query connected by sequential field

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-query

I have a scheme of hierarchical tasks such as this:

```
|-- task_1
|---- task_1_1
|------ task_1_1_1
|------ task_1_1_2
|---- task_1_2
|------ task_1_2_1
|------ task_1_2_2
|-- task_2
etc.
```

The number of tasks at each level can vary as can vary the depth of this hierarchy.

In the database they are stored as a sequence :

| name | sequence | parent_sequence | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| task_1 | 1 | -1 | 1 |
| task_1_1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| task_1_1_1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| task_1_1_2 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| task_1_2 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| task_1_2_1 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| task_1_2_2 | 7 | 5 | 1 |
| task_2 | 8 | -1 | 1 |
| task_b_1 | 1 | -1 | 2 |
| task_b_1_1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| task_b_1_1_1 | 3 | 2 | 2 |

To reproduce the hierarchy, I use this query

```sql
SELECT
    kid.name AS kid_name,
    parent.name AS parent_name
FROM
    task kid
    LEFT JOIN task parent ON parent.sequence = kid.parent_sequence 
                             AND parent.project_id = kid.parent_id
```

When I try to use a hierarchical query as such

```sql
SELECT
    task.name AS task_name,
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(task.name, '/') AS task_path
FROM
   task
START WITH task.parent_sequence = -1
CONNECT BY PRIOR task.sequence = task.parent_sequence
```

it doesn't account for the condition `parent_id = parent_id`.

I tried to hardcode a `WHERE parent_id = 1` and a `LEFT JOIN` to be able to do a `AND kid.project_id = parent.project_id` in the `CONNECT BY PRIOR` and other combinations, but each time, it builds the hierarchy on the integral of the records.

Matching `task.sequence = task.parent_sequence`, hence false duplicates like `task_1/task_b_1_1`.

The problem being that multiple records can hold the same `parent_sequence` and `sequence` (because they are calculated in the scope of one `project_id`).

I can not touch the db schematic.

How can I build a hierarchical query grouped by `project_id`?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `project_id` comparison to the `CONNECT BY` filter:

```sql
SELECT project_id,
       task.name AS task_name,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(task.name, '/') AS task_path
FROM   task
START WITH task.parent_sequence = -1
CONNECT BY
      PRIOR task.sequence = task.parent_sequence 
AND   PRIOR project_id    = project_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY project_id, sequence
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE task (name, sequence, parent_sequence, project_id) AS
SELECT 'task_1',       1, -1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_1_1',     2,  1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_1_1_1',   3,  2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_1_1_2',   4,  2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_1_2',     5,  1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_1_2_1',   6,  5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_1_2_2',   7,  5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_2',       8, -1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_b_1',     1, -1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_b_1_1',   2,  1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'task_b_1_1_1', 3,  2, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PROJECT_ID | TASK_NAME | TASK_PATH |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | task_1 | /task_1 |
> | 1 | task_1_1 | /task_1/task_1_1 |
> | 1 | task_1_1_1 | /task_1/task_1_1/task_1_1_1 |
> | 1 | task_1_1_2 | /task_1/task_1_1/task_1_1_2 |
> | 1 | task_1_2 | /task_1/task_1_2 |
> | 1 | task_1_2_1 | /task_1/task_1_2/task_1_2_1 |
> | 1 | task_1_2_2 | /task_1/task_1_2/task_1_2_2 |
> | 1 | task_2 | /task_2 |
> | 2 | task_b_1 | /task_b_1 |
> | 2 | task_b_1_1 | /task_b_1/task_b_1_1 |
> | 2 | task_b_1_1_1 | /task_b_1/task_b_1_1/task_b_1_1_1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e57c18a559ddd7a88aa9c9f4528978c)*

Comment: `PRIOR project_id    = project_id` this looks so illegal, but works perfectly. Big thanks!